# how to make ajax request to get the two different view in one template

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

Want to make the ajax request to get all objects of models in one template file

views.py

```
def A(request):
   for model x
   return render(request, "crave/comment.html", {'crave': crave, 'form' : form, 'check':check})

def B(request):
   for model y
   return render(request, "crave/crave.html", {'form' : form,'crave_made':crave_made})
```

model y is foreign key to model x.
Want to display the objects of model x and model y in crave.html template.

For the same how do i make a ajax call to view.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to render HTML pages that contain other HTML pages.
The need for Ajax doesn't become clear from your question.
Would't just using an IFrame do the trick?
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Or do you want to refresh part of your page asynchroneously?

Comment: Hay thanks a lot but i want data from backend to be display in one single html templates. see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286800/not-able-to-get-all-posts-and-comments-in-templates-django